# SWI-Prolog predicates

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and my prof seems to have forgotten to teach the class its basic use. He gave us the task of writing predicates stmt and stmts, with the first predicate looking like:

```
stmt([pass|X], X).
stmt([declare,N|X], X) :- atom(N).
stmt([use,N|X], X) :- atom(N).
```

which then passes the test code stmt([use,x,something,else],[something,else]).

The second part looks like the following:

> define a stmts predicate such that `{stmts(List1, List2)}` is provable if `(List1)` starts with atoms that match the (stmts) nonterminal and then continues with the atoms in `List2`. For example, the following query should produce true:
>   `stmts([pass,use,x,more,stuff],[more,stuff])`.

I don't understand how exactly to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works because of the *unification* process in Prolog and the fact that a list in Prolog is a *linked list*.

First of all it might be useful to understand that a list is implement in a [CONS-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) (the term originates from Lisp if I recall correctly). That means that there is a functor (let's here use `cons/2` for simplicity), such that a list, `[use,x,something,else]` is structured like `cons(use,cons(x,cons(something,cons(else,nil))))` (`nil` being the end of the list). So in a linked-list fashion.

Next if you "call a predicate in Prolog" *unification* happens. It aims to unify the arguments in the call with the arguments in the head of the clause. For instance if the head of the claus is `foo(bar(X,qux(Y)))` and you call it with `foo(bar(3,Z))`, then as a result `X = 3` and `Z = qux(Y)` with `X` and `Y` being "uninstantiated variables".

If we combine these two we see that a *desugared* variant of your code would be:

```
stmt(cons(pass,X), X).
stmt(cons(declare,cons(N,X)), X) :- atom(N).
stmt(cons(use,cons(N,X)), X) :- atom(N).
```

So now if we call `stmt(cons(use,cons(x,cons(something,cons(else,nil)))),cons(something,cons(else,nil))).` A unification will happen. First Prolog aim to unify with the first clause:

```
stmt(cons(pass,X),         X)
stmt(cons(use, cons(x,...),cons(something,cons(else,nil)))
```

(I used an ellipse to keep it simple).

The unification will aim to unify the first arguments, like:

```
cons(pass,X) ~ cons(use,cons(else,...))
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

Now the unification will *peel*: remove the first unification, and inject unification of the arguments, so:

```
pass ~ use
X ~ cons(else,...)
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

Now in Prolog `pass` and `use` are *constants* (since these start with a lowercase). Furthermore all constants in Prolog are *different* (except if the have the same "name" so to speak). So since `pass ~ use` cannot unify. The first clause "fails".

In Prolog a *backtracking* mechanism is in place: after the first clause is been called - regardless whether that was a success or a failure - Prolog will retry the call with the second clause, third clause and so on.

So now we aim to unify the call. So now we perform unification like:

```
stmt(cons(declare,cons(N,X  )),X)
stmt(cons(use,    cons(x,...)),cons(something,cons(else,nil)))
```

Which result in unification like:

```
cons(declare,cons(N,X)) ~ cons(use,cons(x,...))
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

again we *peel*:

```
declare ~ use
cons(N,X) ~ cons(x,...)
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

and again that's a fail.

Our final attempt is:

```
stmt(cons(use,cons(N,X)) ,X).
stmt(cons(use,cons(x,...),cons(something,cons(else,nil)))
```

which yields:

```
cons(use,cons(N,X)) ~ cons(use,cons(x,...))
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

and then yields:

```
use ~ use
cons(N,X) ~ cons(x,...)
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

which results into:

```
use ~ use
N ~ x
X ~ ...
X ~ cons(something,cons(else,nil))
```

(the `...` is `cons(something,cons(else,nil))`). So now unification has *succeeded*, hurray. But we are not there yet. Now the *head* of the third clause has succeed, which means we now have to perform calls on the *body* of that clause. So we call:

```
atom(N).
```

and since `N = x`, it means we call `x`. Now `atom(x)` is a builtin, and succeeds (we are not going to do the unification process again here). So that means that the third clause succeeds.

Comment: That explains the first part, can you help with the second part?